# How do I do the following multiple SQL join?

Tags: sql

At the moment I have the following schema

```
DAILY

match_id,user_id,round,score,result, tournament_id
```

At the moment I have a query producing players in order of win percentage, along with points scored and points against e.g.

```
user_id     username    winpercent  totalgames  pointsfor   pointsagainst
3569    User1   100.00000   20  9193    6960
11786   User2   100.00000   11  4549    3859
11932   User3   100.00000   5   1259    1120
```

The query is as follows

```
SELECT PointsFor.user_id,username,
sum(case when PointsFor.result='Won' then 1 Else 0 End)/sum(case when PointsFor.result<>'' Then 1 Else 0 End)*100.0 As winpercent,
sum(case when PointsFor.result<>'' Then 1 Else 0 End) as totalgames,
sum(PointsFor.score) as pointsfor,
sum(PointsAgainst.score) as pointsagainst
FROM users,`daily` PointsFor
JOIN `daily` PointsAgainst
  on PointsFor.match_id = PointsAgainst.match_id
  and PointsFor.user_id <> PointsAgainst.user_id
where PointsFor.user_id=users.id and
    PointsFor.tournament_id=24        
group by user_id
order By WinPercent desc, totalgames desc
```

I want to add one further restriction based on round and result.  Basically I want to restrict to a particular range of rounds and a particular range of results.  I've tried adding the following

```
JOIN (select user_id from daily where round > 25 and (result='Won' or result='Lost')) recent on PointsFor.user_id = recent.user_id
```

Just above my where clause but I end up getting double the results i.e.  Totalgames is 20 when it should only be 10 etc.  What's the proper way to do this join?

Answer (score -1):

after the on of first join, put the second join. and then your where clauses.

```
SELECT PointsFor.user_id,username,
sum(case when PointsFor.result='Won' then 1 Else 0 End)/sum(case when PointsFor.result<>'' Then 1 Else 0 End)*100.0 As winpercent,
sum(case when PointsFor.result<>'' Then 1 Else 0 End) as totalgames,
sum(PointsFor.score) as pointsfor,
sum(PointsAgainst.score) as pointsagainst
FROM users,`daily` PointsFor
JOIN `daily` PointsAgainst
  on PointsFor.match_id = PointsAgainst.match_id
```

then

```
JOIN (select user_id from daily where round > 25 and (result='Won' or result='Lost')) recent on PointsFor.user_id = recent.user_id\
```

then

```
where PointsFor.user_id <> PointsAgainst.user_id
and  PointsFor.user_id=users.id and
    PointsFor.tournament_id=24        
group by user_id
order By WinPercent desc, totalgames desc
```

Comment: I'm still getting double results